# Effect of Reynolds number on shear stress (skin friction drag)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, aerodynamics, turbulence

in this chart:

we see that as Reynolds number increase, skin friction decreases for both layers (laminar and turbulent). now if we assume that increase in reynolds number is due to the increase in velocity so more velocity causes more shear stress and then more skin friction. can anyone explain this contradiction?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That the drag coefficient decreases does not mean that the force decreases.

Remember that the drag coefficient is the dimensionless relation between the resistance felt by the object over the dynamic pressure ($1/2 \rho v^2$) multiplied by the cross-sectional area of the object, which increases quadratically with the Reynolds number.

The decrease of the Reynolds number simply indicates a less-than-quadratic increase in the force, not a drop in it.

Comment: In the skin friction formula, the Rebnolds number is also the denominator of the fraction so what conclusion can be drawn in the end?

Comment: It is the same reasoning. The skin friction (stress) increases with Re, but not as fast as the dynamic pressure. Thus, the skin friction coefficient has the Re in the denominator. But note that the dynamoc pressure increases proportionally to Re^2.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if you think it is good?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the famous "drag crisis" there is indeed a decrease in drag when speed increases.

But this is an exceptional case, still used in golf balls or soccer balls.
See : [wikipedia : drag crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_crisis)